# Get a navigation goal from laserscan

Tags: navigation, laserscan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

For some purpose, I want to publish a navigation goal(`type geometry_msgs::PoseStamped` ). Now I want to get the position and orientation from the laserscan data as fellows, how can i make it?

```
float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t];
float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + i * scan_msg->angle_increment;
```

the laserscan frame_id = "laser", the map frame_id = "map", and I have the tf tree `laser->base_link->odom->map`.

Any suggestions.
Thank You In Advance!!!

**EDIT**

I have solve the problem at this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/246991/get-rotation-between-two-frames/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246927/get-a-navigation-goal-from-laserscan/) by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-03**:
Could you please post your last edit as an *answer*, and then accept your own answer? That shows much more clearly that your question was answered than if you close it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a little unclear on what you actual question is but I'll offer some advice.

Obtaining your current location based on laser scan data can be done with something like the [amcl package](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) that compares the laser scans to a known map.

You can create a map from laser scan data using [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) or manually using GIMP (just export as .gmp).

An easy way to publish a Navigation Goal is to use RVIZ. You can select the 2D Nav goal button at the top which allows you to place an arrow on the screen of where you want the nav goal to be.

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-02**:
Hi,shoemakelevy,

I'm sorry for my poor English.

I want to publish a Navigation Goal, and the Goal's position is obtaining from a laserscan range `float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t]` ,and the Goal's orientation is get from a angle `float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + i * scan_msg->angle_increment;`

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-11-02**:
No problem. I'm still a bit confused about your application. Is your laser scan being taken from your robots position? Are you then trying to obtain a navigation goal? If so which range do you want to use? It looks like you have an array. Also can you explain your angle calculation?

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-02**:
Hi,

The laserscan is taken from my robots, the frame is `laser`, I want to obtain a navigation goal from the laserscan, `float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t];float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + t * scan_msg->angle_increment`, here the `t` is constant, obtained by calculation. Not an array, just one data

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-02**:
Just as obtain the navigation goal from a `range`,and a `angle` in a laserscan. The `range` is the specified orientation(`angle`) in the laserscan.

I want to publish the Goal about something interesting, and detect object from the laserscan.